# Conditional format help needed

Tags: excel

I have 11 numbers in cell range  c3 to l3
                         ending c5003 to l5003

also have numbers in cell range starting af3 to aj3
                                  ending af44 to aj44

I'm trying to get the numbers in cell rangec3 to m5003
to change font color to white when those numbers match numbers
in cell range af3 to ak44

I also need the numbers in cell range m3 to m5003
to change to white when they match the numbers in cell range ak3 to ak5003

I can send the spreadsheet with instructions on what I'm trying to do.
Any help you can give me would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) this is a *programming Q&A* site, not an end-user helpdesk; 2) noone will do your job instead of you.

Comment: Don't change the numbers to white. Set a custom number format of `;;;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Highlight the cells or column you want to apply conditional formatting to.
2. Select Conditional Formatting > New Rule
3. Select "Format only cells that contain"
4. Select "Cell Value" in First drop-down and "equal to" in second drop-down
5. Select the cell selection button to select the range you want to compare the cells or column to.
6. Select the format button to set the desired format.
7. Select Ok.

[Formatting selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCEct.png)